# SublimeText 3 - detect installed syntaxes

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext

How can I detect available syntaxes when running a plugin code?

For example when I invoke

```
output_view.set_syntax_file("Packages/ANSIescape/ANSI.tmLanguage")
```

and ANSIescape package is not installed, then I get an error from Sublime that cannot be caught with `try: ... except:`.

I would like to perform `set_syntax_file` safely, without any error and wish to know if it succeeded or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sublime.find_resources()` to find all of the files that Sublime knows about that are providing syntaxes. That would be all files of type `tmLanguage` (for the older legacy syntax) and `sublime-sytax` for packages using the newer syntax.

There is an example of doing that in [this plugin code](https://github.com/STealthy-and-haSTy/SublimeScraps/blob/master/scratch_files/scratch_buffer.py). The relative snippet of code is this:

```python
def syntax_name(self, syntax):
    syntax_file = os.path.basename(os.path.split(syntax)[1])
    return os.path.splitext(syntax_file)[0]

def parse(self, langs, resource_spec):
    for syntax in sublime.find_resources(resource_spec):
        langs[self.syntax_name(syntax)] = syntax

def query_syntax(self):
    langs = {}

    self.parse(langs, "*.tmLanguage")
    self.parse(langs, "*.sublime-syntax")
```

Here the code is building a dictionary with keys that are the language name (as derived from the file name, see the full code for more information) and values that are the full names of the files.